# Homework Help: Evaluate an expression with a "new" operation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem Statement:

> Imagine that a new operational symbol for mathematics has have been developed. This symbol is $\sim$ and is represented by 
>   $$a\sim b=\frac{ab}{a-b}$$
>   Using this new symbol, find the value of $(2\sim3)\sim4$

Any help?

Comment: The answer is $-2.4$. Can you replicate this?

Answer (score 2):

We want to evaluate:
$$(2\sim3)\sim4$$

First, simplify the parenthesis.  Note that, for the part in the parenthesis, $a=2, b=3$.
$$a\sim b = \frac{ab}{a-b}$$
$$2\sim3 = \frac{(2)(3)}{2-3}$$
$$2\sim3 = \frac{6}{-1} = -6$$

Now, your expression is:
$$(-6)\sim4$$

I'll leave the rest for you to do.  If you need more help (or need more of the problem worked out), let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you meant
a~b=ab/(a-b)
then 2~3 = 2*3/(2-3) = -6
and (2~3)~4 = (-6)~4
which I will let you work out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a way of viewing these operations that will greatly simplify computing big $\sim$ products.

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm a\sim b\ &=&\rm\ \frac{ab}{a-b}\, =\, \frac{1}{b^{-1}-a^{-1}}\, =\, \frac{1}{b'-a'}\ \ where\ \ x' = x^{-1}\\ \\
\rm\Rightarrow\ \ (a\sim b)' &=&\ \rm b'-a'\\ \\
\rm\Rightarrow\ \ ((a\sim b)\sim c)' &=&\ \rm c'-(a\sim b)'\\ \\ 
&=&\ \rm c'-(b'-a')\\ \\
&=&\,\rm \frac{1}4-\left(\frac{1}3-\frac{1}2\right)\\ \\ \\
&=&\, \frac{3-(4-6)}{12}\, =\, \frac{5}{12} \\ \\
\rm\Rightarrow\ \ (a\sim b)\sim c &=&\rm\ \left(\frac{5}{12}\right)' = \frac{12}5\quad \text{by taking prime of prior}
\end{eqnarray}$$